# Expand QTabWidget inside of QScrollArea with QDesigner

Tags: pyqt, qt-designer, qtabwidget, qscrollarea

I have a QTabWidget inside of a QScrollArea. I need the QScrollArea because otherwise the contents may not fit on a (small) screen.
Now I want to add contents to my individual Tabs (like Patients). Therefore I want to expand the QTabWidget more to the right.
Somehow this seems not to be possible. When I drag the widget to the right, it is partly hidden, see the picture. [[image: QTabWidgetishidden]]
But I don't what causes this. The same happens when I try to expand my QTabWidget to the bottom.
I tried setting sizePolicy on the QTabWidget to "Expanding" but it doesn't help.
Any advice?
Thank you!
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkZgP.png)

Comment: You've not set a layout for the `scrollAreaWidgetContents` (and, actually, not even for `patients`). Whenever you see that small red "forbidden" icon near a widget in the inspector it means that that widget has no layout set. Right click on the `scrollAreaWidgetContents` item on the inspector (or on an empty part of the scroll area) and select a proper layout.

Comment: @musicamante Thank you! I tried that before but I didn't work. I found, I additionally have to change the maximumSize of the scrollAreaWidgetContets.

Comment: No, normally you don't, unless you have specific needs (or you did something else wrong), as having lots of empty and unused space in an otherwise resizable scroll area is unexpected and unnecessary to the user. Just ensure that the area is set with the `widgetResizable` property, add layouts to all containers, and verify that all widgets have proper size policies (the default should normally be left as they are, unless you know what you're doing).